# sum of differences between two rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

[image]

Above is a table and i need to get the total distance covered by tyre.

Looking for a way to get the difference the sum to get the total distance covered.

Each the total distance if gotten by sum of difference between "removal" AND "insert" action sharing.

The end results should be 1100+300 = 1400

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there always are just one `'insert'` and one `'removal'` row per `tyre` and `position`, you can use conditional aggregation to compute the distance covered by tuple, and then add another level of aggregation at `tyre` level:

```
select tyreId, sum(distance_covered) distance_covered
from (
    select 
        tyreId, 
        position, 
        sum(case action when 'removal' then distance else - distance end) distance_covered
    from mytable
    where action in ('insert', 'removal')
    group by tyreId, position
)t
group by tyreId
```

Comment: is there a way i can eliminate those that might have the action as 'insert' inorder to prevent producing a negative sum

Comment: @TogetherMovingForward: you can add `having count(*) = 2` after the `group by` clause in the subquery.